# How to get filepath to file in another folder unix?

Tags: ruby, linux, file, unix

I am trying to write some data in one Ruby file to a file in another folder but I am having trouble identifying the path to get to the file I want to write to.

My current code is:

```
File.write('../csv_fixtures/loans.csv', 'test worked!')
```

And my folder structure is as follows: 
[image]

Where I am trying to run my code in 'run_spec.rb' and write to 'loans.csv'.

Additionally, this is the error I am getting: 
[image]

Comment: In the future, please try not to use screenshots. For the directory printout you can use the [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(Unix)) program to get something you can copy-and-paste, and for the error you can just copy and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the path relative to the working directory, not the file that you call `File.write` from. The working directory is the place you've navigated to through `cd` before calling the ruby code. If you ran `rspec` from the root of your project, then the working directory will also be the root. So, in this case, it looks like it would be `./spec/csv_fixtures/loans.csv`. You can run `puts Dir.pwd` to see the working directory that all paths should be relative to.

If you wanted to something more like `require_relative`, you have to use some sort of workaround to turn it into an absolute path, such as `File.dirname(__FILE__)` which gives the absolute path of the folder containing the current file:

```
path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__, "../csv_fixtures/loans.csv"))
```